# How to convert hierarchical DataFrame back from json?

Tags: json, pandas

I am trying to store a pandas DataFrame with hierarchical row index to a json, and then recover it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': ['a','a','b','b'],
                    'B': ['c','d']*2,
                    'C':range(4),
                    'D':[2*i for i in range(4)]
                   })

df = df.set_index(['A','B'])
jsoned_df = df.to_json()
recovered_df = pd.read_json(jsoned_df)
```

I get `ValueError: No ':' found when decoding object value`. This uses the default value `orient='columns'` in to_json and read_json.

Of all [the possible values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.read_json.html) for `orient`, only `orient='records'` and `orient='values'` do not throw a `ValueError`. But `records` loses the row index and `values` loses the row index and the column index.

To reproduce those attempts:

```
for orientation in ['split','records','index','columns','values']:
    jsoned = df.to_json(orient=orientation)
    try:
        recovered = pd.read_json(jsoned,orient=orientation)
        print recovered
        print orientation + ' WORKED!!'
    except ValueError:
        print orientation + ' didnt work...'
    print
```

Comment: This is an outstanding issue in pandas right now. The workaround is to reset the index before calling `to_json`.

Comment: Thank you! I searched for related questions since I figured I couldn't be the first one, but I searched "hierarchical index" rather than "MultiIndex".